# Returning Null value

Tags: apex, trigger

I getting the field values (*Is_Locked__c* & *Locked_By__c* )from old content version(previous),but these field values are returning NUll.

Use case: For first time on uploading the "new version" of document from chatter feed items, updating the field values  *Is_Locked__c* to "**True**" and *Locked_By__c* to **username**.

And second time when uploading new version for feed item, i am getting the field values (*Is_Locked__c* & *Locked_By__c*) of previous content version and comparing. But i am getting **Null** values for these field values (*Is_Locked__c* & *Locked_By__c*).

I am using the below code and please help me to get updated field values instead null value,instead referring to correct document (Previous content version)?

**Code**

```
Trigger ContentVersionStop_trigger on ContentVersion (before insert, before update) { 

       // Getting the current username
       String userName = UserInfo.getUserName();
       User activeUser = [Select name From User where Username = : userName limit 1];
       String currentusername = activeUser.name;
       system.debug('Current user:' + currentusername );
       system.debug('Trigger New:' + Trigger.new);


   ContentVersion oldCV = [Select Id,CreatedDate, PathOnClient, ContentUrl, Is_Locked__c, Locked_By__c, Title from ContentVersion Order By CreatedDate Desc Limit 1];   

  for (ContentVersion cv : Trigger.new) {

    if (oldCV.Is_Locked__c == NULL && oldCV.Locked_By__c==NULL)
      { 
       system.debug('Into Null Loop:' +oldCV.Is_Locked__c);
      cv.Is_Locked__c='True';
      cv.Locked_By__c=currentusername;
       System.debug('records1 are ' + cv);
      }
      else if(oldCV.Is_Locked__c == 'True' && oldCV.Locked_By__c==currentusername )
      {
      system.debug('Into locked Loop:' +oldCV.Is_Locked__c);
      cv.addError('Version is locked');
      } 
  }
}
```

Comment: You don't need to query old content version. You need to use **Trigger.old** or **Trigger.oldMap**

Comment: Instead of null check, do a blank check as well. like use String.isNotEmpty(oldCV.Is_Locked__c)

Comment: Am i missing anything here? you are updating visu__Is_Locked__c and visu__Locked_By__c in this trigger and checking Is_Locked__c and Locked_By__c , is that the logic? also Is_Locked__c is not a checkbox but a text field?

Comment: @kurunve : If i use Trigger .oldmap, like below. I am getting error. So i queried old version.
 for (ContentVersion cv : Trigger.new) {
     Contentversion Oldcv1= Trigger.oldMap.get(cv.ID);

Error:
     System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object

Comment: @preya mohandoass: Visu is name space prefix. now i removed the visu__ from the code. Is_checked__c is a text field. I am assigning text"True" to this field and using this text for comparison.But I am getting NULL value on querying. Any inputs please..Thanks

Comment: well, Trigger.old and Trigger.oldMap are null in before insert trigger, so you need to update logic to play smooth around that

Comment: best practice: `is_locked__c` should be a Checkbox field and hence will never be null